# Saber cuando se ha tocado un jcombobox

Tags: java

Hola tengo un método que coge el valor de la columna seleccionada en un jtable y mete lo que haya en un jcombobox. Necesito hacer un if == false si no se ha tocado el jcombobox. Pero no sé que poner en el jcombobox. ??? para que me diga si se ha tocado el combobox.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que hacer uso del método de la JComboBox .addActionListener(). Dentro del actionPerformed usas el método getSelectedItem() para saber que opcion pulso de las opciones que muestra el JComboBox.

Ejemplo de código:

```
caja.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
        comboBox.getSelectedItem()
    }
});
```

Luego puedes comprobar que opción pulso con un switch mismo.

Ejemplo más completo:

```
String[] tamanos = { "Pequeno", "Mediano", "Grande", "Enorme" };

JComboBox<String> cajaTamanos = new JComboBox<>(tamanos);
cajaTamanos.addActionListener(this);

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == this.cajaTamanos) {
        JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
        switch ((String) comboBox.getSelectedItem()) {
            case "Pequeno":{
                cambioTamano("pequeno");
                break;
            }
            case "Mediano":{
                cambioTamano("mediano");
                break;
            }
            case "Grande":{
                cambioTamano("grande");
                break;
            }
            case "Enorme":{
                cambioTamano("enorme");
                break;
            }
            default:{
                cambioTamano("");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que me quieres decir. No necesito saber que opción ha seleccionado sino solo saber si lo ha tocado o no. Algo así sería             if (jComboBoxPresidente.hasFocus()==false) { . Pero con has focus no me vale necesitaría algo tipo si ha tenido alguna vez el focus o si se le ha hecho click o algo así. Pero no encuentro ninguna de esas opciones.

Comment: Con el método getSource == this.cajaTamanos ya compruebas si se pulso la caja.